# Strange data parsing issue

Tags: cocoa-touch

in my code I am retrieving the users reminders and displaying them a tableview. 
Whenever I print NSLog in my code, the the tables array gets displayed properly. But whenever I leave out NSLog in my code, my data isn't displayed properly anymore. The value for "title" of the reminder returns (null).

I can reproduce the issue every time. Anyone have any idea what is happening here?

```
- (void)shareReminderButtonAction:(UIButton *)buttonEvent {

EKEventStore *store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

NSPredicate *predicate = [store predicateForRemindersInCalendars:nil];

[store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeReminder completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {

    [store fetchRemindersMatchingPredicate:predicate completion:^(NSArray *reminders) {

        ReminderView *shareRem = [[ReminderView alloc]init];

        NSLog(@"Reminders: %@", reminders);

        UINavigationController *navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:shareRem];
        [navigation setNavigationBarHidden:YES];

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController presentViewController:navigation animated:YES
                                                                                   completion:^(void){[shareRem setArray:reminders];}];

    }];

}];

}
```

Log data with NSLog in my code above:

```
"EKReminder <0x1d5b3630> {title = Gdghv; dueDate = 2013-03-06 22:00:00 +0000; completionDate = (null); priority = 0; calendarItemIdentifier = 0BD2CB76-588B-4103-86B0-D71D22317DC0}"
```

Log data at the UITableViewController end when receiving data without the NSLog in my code above:

```
CADObjectGetInlineStringProperty failed fetching title for EKPersistentReminder with error Error Domain=NSMachErrorDomain Code=268435459 "The operation couldn\342\200\231t be completed. (Mach error 268435459 - (ipc/send) invalid destination port)"

"EKReminder <0x1c5e6fd0> {title = (null); dueDate = (null); completionDate = (null); priority = 0; calendarItemIdentifier = (null)}"
```

Thanks alot!

Comment: You used inappropriate tags *only.* Congrats...

Comment: I found out the problem I was having. The EKEventStore was obviously releasing too soon. I put it in my viewDidLoad method and everything worked out fine!

Answer (score 0):

The EKEventStore object needs to be kept around for the entire time you are using Event Kit objects. It's normally best to house it within a singleton. From [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/ReadingAndWritingEvents.html):

> An EKEventStore object requires a relatively large amount of time to
>   initialize and release. Consequently, you should not initialize and
>   release a separate event store for each event-related task. Instead,
>   initialize a single event store when your app loads, and use it
>   repeatedly to ensure that your connection is long-lived.
>
> An event store instance must not be released before other Event Kit
>   objects; otherwise, undefined behavior may occur.